# Can i change a setting in Chrome so streams no longer freeze when they are in a non-displayed tab?

Tags: google-chrome, video, freeze

I watch a lot of Twitch in Chrome, and Google made a change earlier this year so that video content playing in a tab which isn't currently selected has the visual part of the video frozen until the tab is selected again. The audio still works fine, but the video is frozen. This is good for saving processor time, but it does lead to the unfortunate result that when I switch back to that tab, the video still appears frozen for a second or so until the player catches up. This means that if I react to an audio cue while in another tab, I usually miss what the audio cue is about.

Is there a way to make the visuals continue playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chrome://flags set "Optimize background video playback" to Disabled.